# Prove a class of regular languages is not closed under a weird concatenation operation

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

Let's say we have an operation $L$ and a language $S$. $L(S) = \{s^n ~|~ s \in S, n \geq 0\}$. How can I prove a class of regular languages is not closed under this operation?

Comment: The grammar of your question is all wrong. I think you mean to say: "We *define* the following operation $L$ on the class of languages. For a language $S$, $L(S)=\dots$. How can I prove *the* class of regular languages is not closed under this operation."

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes.. Sorry for the confusion, I have been trying to figure this out in the last few hours without any luck..

Comment: You have included "pumping lemma" as a tag. How have you tried to apply the pumping lemma to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Let $L = ab^*$. Show that
$$
S(L) \cap ab^*ab^* = \{ab^nab^n \mid n \geqslant 0 \}
$$
and prove that this language is not regular.